# Solve floor equation

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

We have this equation over real numbers: $ \lfloor x^2 \rfloor = x+6$ . How we can solve it without guessing the answers?

My try: I tried to solve it in several intervals and found $-2$ and $3$ as answers but I can't deduct that there isn't any solution in other intervals .

Comment: Well, since $x+6$ is an integer iff $x$  is, we get that, for a solution, we must actually have $x^2=x+6$.

Comment: In general for problems like this (if, for instance, the $6$ were $6.2$) from $\lfloor x^2 \rfloor = x+6$, you can deduce that $x+5 \le x^2 < x+6$ (for $x + 5 > 0$; for the signs, you have to make up other pairs of inequalities; the messiest is when the floor is zero.). In this case, though, @lulu's answer is clearly a winner.

Comment: Yes , It's impossible sometimes to make up pair of inequalities . Can you provide a good reference to study how we can make up these pairs for solving floor equations?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Can you provide some examples ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since LHS is a integer that implies $x+6$ is a integer which then implies that $x$ is a integer.Since $x\in\Bbb{Z}$ we know that $\lfloor x^2\rfloor=x^2$
Hence we have that
$$x^2-x-6=0\\x_{1,2}=-2,3$$
Just a note if one of the solutions wasn't a integer then that soulution wouldn't satisfy the equation.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks